# Reconfiguring Capybara-webkit when redirecting all subdomains to 'www'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, subdomain, capybara-webkit

I have a Rails 3.2 app using a naked domain (e.g. `doma.in`) and I'd like to redirect all subdomains (including root) to `www.doma.in`.

The gem [rack-www](https://github.com/stjhimy/rack-www) does this nicely. However, now all of my integration tests are breaking. I'm using Capybara-webkit and Turnip.

Help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a post on testing sub domains. It may not be the exact solution but it shows how to set the app host etc

http://blog.jamesalmond.com/testing-subdomains-using-capybara/

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just setting the redirect in the `config/environments/staging||production.rb` files and my tests passed just fine.